# How to copy remote build files localy as needed?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I have a remote server that has cpp header files and endstates (lib/dll/exe) needed to compile projects.  Using the remote server when compiling takes a lot of time with the added overhead of going over the network.  I would like to copy the files locally, but most of the files on the remote server I do not need in order to compile my projects.  Ideally, I would like to setup a locally mounted drive that uses the remote server file setup, but copies the files I need locally as I try to read them.  This way over the corse of a day/week, I can build a local cache of only the files I need.

Is there a way to achieve this or something similar?  My goal is to have a local cache without too many extra files that I won't ever need to compile.

Current, I have a script that uses robocopy to copy what I need locally, but it is difficult to identify what I actually need so I end up pulling more files than nessisary, taking up extra hard-drive space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a back-up program?  Most of them will quickly copy defined directories/files to defined locations.

Cobian back-up (freeware) would do exactly what you need, but there must be dozens of others, so just pick a UI that you like.